# How can I get the name of the city from all the retrieved data using here reverse-geocoding?

Tags: javascript, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I'm working with the [here](https://www.here.com/) reverse-geocoding feature and with the code below the console prints an Object with all the information of my location. I'd like to just get the name of the city where I am. How can I do that?. Thank you!
(In my code I've given a value to the "platform" variable.)

```
var geocoderService = platform.getGeocodingService();
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position =>{
      geocoderService.reverseGeocode(
        {
          mode: 'retrieveAddress',
          maxresults: 1,
          prox: position.coords.latitude + ', ' + position.coords.longitude
        },
        success => {
          console.log(success.Response);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Not working.')

  }
```

Comment: Could you add to your question an example of the response you're getting, and what you'd like to extract?

Comment: Nevermind, I achieved it.  It was by writing `success.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.Address.City` in the code. Still thank you! @phuzi

Comment: You should be able to dive into your Response object to get particular sub-properties like "city". Try printing the Response to see its structure, then using dot notation to get the target property (E.g. if the Response object looks sommething like `{ View : [ { Result : [ { Location : { address : "", city : "", zip : "" } } ] } ] }`, you would use `let city = Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.city`). This documentation might help clarify things: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/geocoding.html

Comment: Ah, I see you discovered that while I was writing up the example. Well done. You could put it as an answer to your own question if your think it might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that information by writing `success.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.Address.City` in the code.